# How to get widget size after device reboot (For Android 4.4.4)

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget, where its layout should change according to current widget size. I use the following code to handle such requirement.

```
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context,
                                      AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                      int appWidgetId,
                                      Bundle newOptions) {
    int heightInDp = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);
    int heightInCell = getCellSize(heightInDp);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = org.yccheok.jstock.gui.widget.Utils.getRemoteViews(appWidgetId, getWidgetWatchlistFragmentResourceId(context, appWidgetId));
    if (heightInCell >= 3) {
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.header, View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.header, View.GONE);
    }
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
}
```

This works pretty well. Till I realize in Android 4.4.4, when you power down and power up your device, only `onUpdate` will be triggered.

However, in 4.1.2, `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged` will be triggered. In such case, it is far easier for me to handle UI layout according to widget size. As in `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged`, we received `Bundle newOptions`. From the bundle, we can query for current widget size.

However, how can we get widget size in `onUpdate`? Or, in another word, how can we get widget size, after device reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only workable for device with Jelly Bean and above.

It seems there's an API to achieve such purpose.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    Bundle bundle = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId);
    heightInDp = bundle.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);
}
```